# gdb: Get last changes of value

Tags: c, gdb, watch

I have a C-application which has a bug: There's a value (at a specific location in an static array; so the address is well-known) which has at some point an unexpected value. I've tried these things:

- Using address sanitizer: It did not detect anything
- Using watch-point: Unfortunately the value can change many many times in a valid way until the change is invalid. Even the final value might an will appear many times (which is valid). So it's not possible to check for a specific value.

As soon as the value is "unexpected", the application will hang (basically a spin-lock will loop forever). If this happens I would like to get the last changes for the specific address.

Is it somehow possible to do this with gdb?

Thank you very much

-edit-

It would already be sufficient to always dump the stacktrace when the value changes and automatically continue. I'm not sure if that's easily possible with gdb.

Comment: About a value at a specific memory address

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but you could create an unbuffered(!) log file (or simply use `stderr`, which is also unbuffered) that is written to whenever you expect the value to change. You could write to the log file the value before the intended change, and then afterwards again, this time with the value after the intended change. That way, you can see in the log file whether the value after the last intended change is identical to the value before the next intended change. If these values are not identical, then you know that the value is being modified by an unintended source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already know that the value is changed from a unintended location. The intended changes are already recorded and trivial.

Comment: Since you appear to be using multiple threads, you may want to also see if [ThreadSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html) reports anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using watch-point: Unfortunately the value can change many many times in a valid way until the change is invalid. Even the final value might an will appear many times (which is valid). So it's not possible to check for a specific value.

A GDB watchpoint does not only support breaks if the value at a particular memory address changes to a particular value. It also supports more complex conditional expressions, such as:

```
enable_break && intended_value != actual_value
```

In the comments section, you stated that the intended changes are trivial and that you are sure that the value is being modified from an unintended source. Therefore, if `actual_value` is the value that is being modified from an unintended source, then you could introduce a new variable with `static` lifetime called `intended_value`, which you set to the same value as `actual_value` whenever you intentionally change the value of this variable.

However, using the expression

```
intended_value != actual_value
```

by itself would have the problem that you cannot set a new value for both variables at the same time, and modifying the variables one after the other would trigger the watchpoint.

In order to prevent the watchpoint from triggering whenever you change the value of these variables, you can change the expression to the following:

```
enable_break && intended_value != actual_value
```

The variable `enable_break` should be a `bool` with `static` lifetime, which specifies whether the watchpoint should be active or not.

Whenever you want to assign a new value to `intended_value` and `actual_value`, you can set `enable_break` to `false`, set both variables to the new values, and then reenable the watchpoint by setting `enable_break` to `true`. That way, the watchpoint will never trigger when you intentionally assign a new value to these variables.

Note however that according to the [GDB documentation on watchpoints](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html), software watchpoints may not detect if another thread changes the expression of the watchpoint.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, the *best* way to debug a problem like this is by using reversible debugger, such as [rr](https://rr-project.org/).

It allows you to e.g. run until crash or corruption, then set watch point and do `reverse-cont` to go back to where the value was last updated.

This works in your case -- where corruption is repeatable, and *also* in the case where random memory is corrupted -- since `rr` replays the run *exactly*, there is no variability during reverse execution.